# why the color transition only works on back way CSS

Tags: css, css-transitions

im trying to change the text color faster than the anything else but on going way the transition works on all but not color and on way back the transition works on all and color too .
why on the first transition the color won't work

```css
#home-section button {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #eee8e8;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#home-section article {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s, color 1s;
  transition: all 3s, color 1s;
}

#home-section button:focus + article {
  width: 670px;
  height: 500px;
  line-height: 180%;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: #797879 #252625;
  background: #625b6b;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

#home-section button:focus {
  background-color: #252625;
  color: #eee8e8;
}
```

this is the html it's a react component

```js
import React from 'react';
import './styles/Home.css';

function Main() {
    return (
        <section id="home-section">
            <h1>Hi,</h1>
            <h2>My Name is Elmahdi,</h2>
            <h2>And I'm a Front-End Web Developer.</h2>
            <button>Read My story</button>
            <article>
                texttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf texttexttextextefgzehgozsfzenf text
            </article>
        </section>
    )
}

export default Main
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML? Also, try to add transitions property to #home-section button and see if that works.

Comment: @Chipsy i added the html

Comment: @Chipsy and i try that it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did this to do what i was looking for

```css
article {
    background: #625b6b;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: transparent;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1s, color 0.5s ease 0ms;
  }
  button:focus + article {
    visibility: visible;
    width: 670px;
    height: 500px;
    line-height: 180%;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: #797879 #252625;
    background: #625b6b;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: all 1.5s, color 0.85s ease-out 500ms;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The color is transitioning at 1 second at the beginning but the background transition creates the illusion that the color takes 3 seconds on the initial transition. If you set the initial background color to #625b6b, you will see that the color is only taking 1 second for the initial transition.

Here is an example with the background color being set to #625b6b by default.

```css
#home-section button {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: auto;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #eee8e8;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#home-section article {
  background: #625b6b;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s, color 1s;
  transition: all 3s, color 1s;
}

#home-section button:focus+article {
  width: 670px;
  height: 500px;
  line-height: 180%;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: #797879 #252625;
  background: #625b6b;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

#home-section button:focus {
  background-color: #252625;
  color: #eee8e8;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-section">
  <button>Button</button>
  <article>
    This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: the color transition is still not working